# Laravel cloned repository docker composer unable to create vendor

Tags: linux, laravel, docker, ubuntu, laravel-sail

I recently got a new working PC with Ubuntu 22.04 on it. I pulled down my repo from Github and decided to give running everything through docker containers a try.

I found a script on laravel docs in order to run composer install through a container.

```
docker run --rm \
-u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
-v $(pwd):/var/www/html \
-w /var/www/html \
laravelsail/php81-composer:latest \
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Instantly I'm getting an issue saying

```
In Filesystem.php line 254:

/var/www/html/vendor does not exist and could not be created.
```

I've read through the documentation, but I can't seem to find anything. I've been googling for hours and keep finding people saying stuff about chown etc. but that just messes things up even worse.

I tried installing a brand new application through

```
curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app" | bash
```

Here I have sail installed and run sail up, but when I try to run composer install or npm install, I get permission issues again.

I'm about to lose my mind here, so I hope someone will be able to help me out.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem today, and I was able to determine that Docker Desktop was the cause (mainly due to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/laravel/sail/issues/435)). I was able to resolve my issue by [switching my docker context to use Docker Engine](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/linux-install/#context):

```
 $ docker context use default
```

If you are not using Docker Desktop, then I do not know what the solution might be. Setting the folder permissions to `777` did work for me, but like you I was not satisfied with that as an answer.